# Accessing a folder in Google Drive from Colaboratory

Tags: python, directory, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I want to be able to read and write files to a folder in Google Drive from Colaboratory but cannot figure how to access a specific folder.

I successfully mounted my drive, and then did a file listing.  The listing shows the directory I am interested (edited for brevity), so I attempt to change to the directory but get an error.

```
 from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive')

    Drive already mounted at /content/drive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True)

import os
os.listdir()
```

Output (edited)

*['99 Temp',
 '02 Work',
 '01 Home',
 'Home-Building-Key-Facts-Sheet.pdf',
 'Home-Contents-Key-Facts-Sheet.pdf',
 .....,
 'Travel Insurance Allianz Certificate of Insurance.pdf',
 'Data']*

```
os.chdir("drive/Data")
os.listdir()

*FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-853a98f4629a> in <module>()
----> 1 os.chdir("drive/Data")
      2 os.listdir()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drive/Data'*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move to the 'Data' directory listed in the last element of your edited output, please try this. It looks like you are already in `/content/drive`.

```py
os.chdir("Data")
os.listdir()
```

You can confirm your current working directory by `pwd` command.

```
!pwd
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on assumption that the 'Data' folder in Google Drive is saved under **My Drive** folder (which is normal by default for Google Drive)

```
import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Data")
```

```
!pwd
```